# jQuery.wrap HTML elements with a div that does not do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, jquery-wrap

Assume there is a complex website with many styles etc. There are also many images on that site that may be positioned, inline, block, or whatever.

What I want to do is to put a little overlay icon above each image!

First attempt was to just create a `position:absolute` `span` for each image icon for each image at the end of body and move it over the image. Problem: If something on the websites moves, hides, or shows then the image might move too but the icon overlay would stay thus the icon would not be over the image anymore.

So I would like to use `jQuery.wrap` to wrap each image in a div with `position:relaitve` then I put the icon overlay also in that div and position it inside the div. So if `div`+`image` move, the icon will move too.

Problem is that the div must somehow be uninfluential on the context and the website structure and the dom, so that it does not break the layout of the website. How can I create such a "neutral" div?

Simplified version of my code:

```
$("img:visible").each(function(i, v){
    var img = $(this);
    var position = img.offset();
    $('<span class="icon" />')
    .css({
        'top': position['top'] + 5,
        left': position['left'] + 5
    })
    .appendTo(document.documentElement)
}
//css
.icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 50000;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're working with?

Comment: Get it working with hard-coded HTML/CSS, then work out how to automate things with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: well my code already works and shows the overlay icons correctly. But if i do $('body').prepend('<div style="height:300px" />'); then all images get move down by 300px, but not the icons! unfortunately i can not track all such inserts or deletions of elements to update my icon overlays.....

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a block level element, it'll have the potential to mess with the flow of your HTML. Instead use a `<span>` element, which will wrap around the image but not add its own structure to the page:

```
$(function () {
    $("img").wrap('<span class="img-overlay" />');
});
```

Then you can add whatever CSS to a `.img-overlay` class, for instance a background image as a watermark.

If you want to wrap the images in more HTML, you can add it all at once like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("img").wrap(
        $('<span class="img-overlay" />').append(
            $('<span class="img-underlay" />')
        )
    );
});
```

I suggest trying to use as few elements as possible as it will create a smoother experience for your users.

Comment: assume that the image is somehow float:right or something. Wouldnt the span mess that up?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the following rules in CSS:

```
img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}    

.frame {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(https://jsdotgit.com/js-small.gif)no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 2vw;
  height: 4vh;
}
```

The jQuery should [**.wrap()**](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) a `<figure class="frame">` around [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `<img>` and insert a `<figcaption class="logo">` [**.before()**](http://api.jquery.com/before/) each `<img>`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    var frame = `<figure class='frame'></figure>`;
    var logo = `<figcaption class='logo'></figcaption>`;
    $(this).wrap(frame).before(logo);
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.l {
  width: 18vw
}

.m {
  width: 9vw
}

.s {
  width: 6vw
}

.frame {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  height: auto;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url(https://jsdotgit.com/js-small.gif)no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 2vw;
  height: 4vh;
}
```

```html
<main class='gallery'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg' class='l'>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='m'>
  </section>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='l'>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg" class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='s'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='s'>
  </section>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='l'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='l'>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg' class='s'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg" class='m'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='m'>
  </section>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg' class='l'>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg" class='l'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='l'>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg' class='s'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg" class='m'>
  </section>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg' class='l'>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg' class='m'>
  </section>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='l'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='l'>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='m'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/dp8G9Fr.jpg' class='s'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='m'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/MEPxbq4.jpg' class='m'>
  </section>
  <section class='column'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/ydfYXqh.jpg' class='s'>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/AXUJEUS.jpg" class='s'>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/DrEwPH0.jpg' class='s'>
  </section>
</main>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```